# Find a Probability of Coin flip event

Tags: probability

We have two coins one is fair coin another one load coin. If we flip load coin, probability of heads is $0.7$ and if we flip fair coin, probability of heads is $0.5$. What is the $p(\text{heads on flip one OR flip two})$?

Comment: $1-P(\text{both tails})$

Comment: You should post your attempts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your space of events is {HH, HT, TH, TT}. Then:

$P($H on flip 1 OR H on flip 2$)= P(HH)\cup P(HT)\cup P(TH)=1-P(TT)=0.85$